# What is the designated initializer for SKLabel node in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I was wondering what the designated initalizer for SKLabelNode is in the Swift programming language with SpriteKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[init(fontNamed:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKLabelNode/initWithFontNamed:) is the designated initializer. Convenience initializers have the convenience keyword.

Comment: When I tried to subclass SKLabelNode on 10.13, I also needed to override required init?(coder aDecoder:) and init()